# How can I custom URL on php?

Tags: php, url, slash

https://example.com/cart.php
https://example.com/total.php

And I want to do this
https://example.com/cart/total.php

I search it on the internet and I find friendly URL but that not work me because of all tutorials and blog with friendly URL talk about how to hide .php?id=x from URL, and that is not my problem, Please help me I need help for it and can continue

Answer (score 0):

You need to past total.php file into cart folder. So you can use this as url.

Comment: But If I do it it will be

Comment: https://example.com/cart/index.php I want https://example.com/cart.php and https://example.com/cart/total.php

Comment: I have answer but I need some more information what you are trying to do. Explain me what you are facing right now and what you are looking for.

Comment: I need have a url with good structure, I have on cart php the list of the products and on total.php the total prices to pay and I try add it on a folder named cart but this look bad  /cart/index.php  /cart/total.php  I want do /cart  and cart/total

Comment: can I do it with remove trailing slash?

Comment: You need to work with .htaccess file search on Google how to use rewrite for url, you can change /cart/index.php with /cart by add a code in .htaccess but if you use this code you need to give page link like /cart it's simple.